# Golang Sort adds extra values to map

Tags: sorting, go

```
type GeoNameTally struct {
    Id    uint32
    Count uint32
}

type Tally map[uint32]GeoNameTally
```

Above are the structs i have. The idea is pretty simple. I'm just tallying how many times something occurs.

```
func (t Tally) Len() int           { return len(t) }
func (t Tally) Less(i, j int) bool { return t[uint32(i)].Count < t[uint32(j)].Count }
func (t Tally) Swap(i, j int)      { t[uint32(i)], t[uint32(j)] = t[uint32(j)], t[uint32(i)] }
```

Everything works perfectly fine until I get to the sort. Right before sort, the map looks fine:

```
map[1043487:{Id:1043487 Count:1} 1043503:{Id:1043503 Count:1} 1043444:{Id:1043444 Count:1} 1043491:{Id:1043491 Count:1} 1043459:{Id:1043459 Count:1} 1043475:{Id:1043475 Count:1} 1043464:{Id:1043464 Count:1} 1043441:{Id:1043441 Count:1} 1043470:{Id:1043470 Count:1} 1043460:{Id:1043460 Count:1}]
```

However right after `sort.Sort(myTally)` the map has extra and empty values as you can see from the following output:

```
map[1043503:{Id:1043503 Count:1} 1043491:{Id:1043491 Count:1} 1043459:{Id:1043459 Count:1} 1043475:{Id:1043475 Count:1} 4:{Id:0 Count:0} 8:{Id:0 Count:0} 1043487:{Id:1043487 Count:1} 1:{Id:0 Count:0} 5:{Id:0 Count:0} 9:{Id:0 Count:0} 1043470:{Id:1043470 Count:1} 2:{Id:0 Count:0} 6:{Id:0 Count:0} 1043444:{Id:1043444 Count:1} 1043441:{Id:1043441 Count:1} 1043460:{Id:1043460 Count:1} 3:{Id:0 Count:0} 7:{Id:0 Count:0} 1043464:{Id:1043464 Count:1}]
```

Have I done something wrong to the 3 functions?

Comment: Yeah, you used a map. It's unorderd, you can't sort it, stop trying. Use a slice. Also just looked at your data and you're using the `Id` as the key in your map which is redundant, `[]GeoNameTally` order it by `item.Id`. Only way this could be worse is if you do a ton of access by key which the map is much better at. Slice will perform better for any other type of access, iteration ect. The empty values are probably from your wonky assignment which I can't easily say whether or not it's right because it's bad code, hard to read. Use a temp variable, make your assignment clear.

Comment: I am using a map for the exact reason you mentioned. I need to access elements by key and that redundant ID is there for a reason. If you look at golang sort, you have to implement those 3 functions. That wonky assignment you mentioned is how you do it in golang. You don;t need a temp variable like you would in any other language.

Comment: haha well whether or not Go encourages that syntax I'll continue thinking it's very very bad. Anyway, to work around this I'd recommend creating a slice that holds only the key values and sorting that. When you're dealing with ordering related things, use the slice, when you need to access an item, get it out of the map by key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing inexistent indexes to `Swap(i, j)`.

A map type is composite. It is defined in terms of 2 other types: the key type and the value type. Example:

```
map[string]bool
```

In the previous example, `string` is the key type, `bool` is the value type.

As you may know, map access returns 1 or 2 values. In a 1 return value context like yours, a map access will return the zero-value for the map's value type when given an inexistent index.

This means that if you access `m["im_not_defined"]` on some map `m` of type `map[string]bool`, you'll get a return value that is the [zero-value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for `bool` (the map's value type).

You can check if the indexes are defined by doing (inside Swap):

```
if a, k := t[uint32(i)]; k {
    t[uint32(j)] = a
} else {
    panic("undefined index")
}
```

And analogously for `j`.

So basically, if `i` is undefined, the zero-value of `GeoNameTally` is assigned to `t[j]` and that causes your "empty" (zero) values.

Anyhow, if you want to *sort* anything, you'll have to use a slice. A map is unordered by definition.

Comment: so accessing an nonexistent index on a map creates an empty element on that index?

Comment: no, it returns the zero-value for the map's value type (the type after the closing square bracket). B in `map[A]B`

Comment: at this point im just trying to figure out how those empty values occurred. Thanks for the help. I think I'll just switch to using a slice. I just didn't want to iterate over the slice over and over to check if certain values exist as I could potentially be iterating over it hundreds of times. Upvoted

Comment: That clarifies a lot. This actually answers my question as to why it is creating those empty elements in the map. Thanks

Comment: @khuderm: you can also use [`sort.Search`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) with a sorted slice to find elements in `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Go 1.8, there is an easier way to sort a slice that does not require you to define new types. You simply create a Less (anonymous) lambda.

```
a := []int{5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i] < a[j]
})
for _, v := range a {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```